# Identify problematic characters in a string

Tags: c#, sql-server, encoding, character-encoding, linq-to-entities

I want to be able to identify problematic characters in a string saved in my sql server using LINQ to Entities.

Problematic characters are characters which had problem in the encoding process.

This is an example of a problematic string : "testing�stringáאç".

In the above example only the � character is considered as problematic.

So for example the following string isn't considered problematic:"testingstringáאç".
How can I check this Varchar and identify that there are problematic chars in it?

Notice that my preferred solution is to identify it via a LINQ to entities query , but other solutions are also welcome - for example: some store procedure maybe?

I tried to play with Regex and with "LIKE" statement but with no success...

Comment: won't be better way to deal with that by avoid adding to database problematic string? I mean, set correct characters coding (for example 'utf-8').

Comment: Basically you are right, but notice that in my situation there can be several scenarios which can cause this kind of problematic characters. My goal is to build some error notifier which will notify on these errors for further investigation and handling.

Comment: Unicode != "problematic characters". The database and your language of choice both support it, you might want to as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net and NVARCHAR both use Unicode, so there is nothing inherently "problematic" (at least not for BMP characters).

So you first have to define what "problematic" in meant to mean:

- characters are not mapped in target codepages

Simply convert between encodings and check whether data is lost:

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, @originalNVarchar)) = @originalNVarchar
```

Note that you can use SQL Server collations using the COLLATE clause rather than using the default database collation.

- characters cannot be displayed due to the fonts used

This cannot be easily done in .Net

Answer (score 2):

Check out [the Encoding class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hf4sb8.aspx).

It has a [DecoderFallback Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.decoderfallback.aspx) and a [EncoderFallback Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.encoderfallback.aspx) that lets you detect and substitute bad characters found during decoding.

Comment: The solution which you've described is a bit problematic in regarding to the entity framework. The solution which @devio suggested below works in the SQL sever side - but serves my goal. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @StringWithProblem NVARCHAR(20) = N'This is '+NCHAR(8)+N'roblematic';
DECLARE @ProblemChars NVARCHAR(4000) = N'%['+NCHAR(0)+NCHAR(1)+NCHAR(8)+']%'; --list all problematic characters here, wrapped in %[]%

SELECT PATINDEX(@ProblemChars, @StringWithProblem), @StringWithProblem;
```

That gives you the index of the first problematic character or 0 if none is found.

Comment: I understand your solution, it will probably work but I wanted to find more generic solution - like the one that @devio offered above. Thanks